# How do i center a div class?

Tags: html, css, position, containers

I am having trouble centering a div class. I want the div class to be centered in the page as i scroll at the moment it is stuck on the left. I have tried floating it center which did nothing and am just an amateur so not sure what else to try.

HTML

```
<div class = "container">
    <ul>
        <li class = "image">
        <img src = "BlackBox.jpg" height="200px">
        </li>

        <li class = "image">
        <img src = "BlackBox.jpg" height="200px">
        </li>

        <li class = "image">
        <img src = "BlackBox.jpg" height="200px">
        </li><br>

        <li class = "image">
        <img src = "BlackBox.jpg" height="200px">
        </li>

        <li class = "image">
        <img src = "BlackBox.jpg" height="200px">
        </li>

        <li class = "image">
        <img src = "BlackBox.jpg" height="200px">
        </li><br>

        <li class = "image">
        <img src = "BlackBox.jpg" height="200px">
        </li>

        <li class = "image">
        <img src = "BlackBox.jpg" height="200px">
        </li>

        <li class = "image">
        <img src = "BlackBox.jpg" height="200px">
        </li>   


    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image {
display: inline;
padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
}

.container {
width: 700px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
.container{
    width: 700px;
     margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

see demo http://jsfiddle.net/JentiDabhi/4q9j40m1/

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
.container {
    width: 700px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of your container width.

Change container `width:500px` or any other and see the result.

You can center your div using `align-self` property.

```
.container {
        width: 500px;
        align-self: center;
        -webkit-align-self: center;
}
```

Check [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/c9cmwzkw/)

Comment: That didnt center it. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to center things you know. Horizontal center is one thing, vertical center is another.

For horizontal centering things are pretty easy.

1: give the body a fixed width, and then `margin: 0 auto;`

```
.parent {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* for block level */
.parent {
    text-align: center;
}

/* for inline, inline-block */
.parent {
    position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

For vertical centering
1: Set the `line-height` to some value greater than the font-size,

```
.child {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 24px;
}
/* downside, works for single line text */
```

for images

```
.parent {
    line-height: 200px; /* greater than image size */
}

.child img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

2: Table Way

```
.parent {
    display: table;
}

.child {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
/* this is equivalent to valign = middle from <table></table> days */
```

3: Positioning

```
.parent: {
    position: relative;
}

.child: { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    /* brings the top left corner to center */
    height: 30%;
    width: 50%;
    margin: -15% 0 0 -25%;
    /* set the top and left margins to half the height and width */
}
```

4: Equal top and bottom padding

```
.parent { 
    padding: 5% 0;
}
.child {
    padding: 10% 0;
}
```

There are some mentioned [here](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/), check'em out.